# Regarding TechJoomla's Common Payment API

Tags: component

I am using TechJoomla's Common Payment API for my own component. (https://techjoomla.com/common-payment-api)

It seems that the demo component dosen't work. I have a more or less blank component as shown in the image below.

[image]

Is it that the API doesn't work with my Joomla version? I am using Joomla! 3.3.6 Stable [ Ember ].  Does anyone have a solution for this?

It also seems that Common Payment API dosen't have a good documentation to look to. I could be wrong, but if anyone does have the link to the documentation, please let me know.

Also, does anyone know what is the most commonly used open source payment api for joomla?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Sameer. Welcome to JSE :) 2 questions for you. Have you enabled the payment plugin? Have you configured it?

Comment: More information can be found here https://github.com/techjoomla/joomla-payments

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @moomoochoo , Yes, I have enabled the payment plugin already and set the settings too. The only good documentation seems to be the slideshare, but that is a bit vague too. Have you had success with this API? If so, in which version of Joomla? Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that I've done nothing with this API yet. I just remember cos it looked interesting. I did however find a free component (Digistore) that apparently uses the API. It might be worth taking a look at what they have done -> http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/e-commerce/shopping-cart/digistore Some other paid components that use the API are listed here http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/e-commerce/payment-gateway/stripe-payment-for-common-payment-api

Answer (score 2):

You can open up the code of the component to learn more about the plugin triggers that you'll need to use for calling the specific payment functions. There's a slide deck that explains the process and the triggers to use here - http://www.slideshare.net/coolparth/joomla-common-payments-api

You should be pretty much set by looking at the slides.

Currently there's no 'standard' API for payments in Joomla, and CPG is an effort to do exactly that. Right now most e-commerce extensions have their own APIs.

Disclaimer : I'm CTO, Techjoomla and maintainer of the CPG repository.

Comment: Ping: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/28781/12352  If you don't mind, please have a look.